# getElementById Java Script Html doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, forms, getelementbyid

The above Html (part of an Html page) and JavaScript codes are supposed to check the validity of User Name. 
The code doesn't work (I didn't understand if I need to use `var username = document.getElementById('text_UserName').value;` or `var username = document.getElementById('text_UserName')`). 
 
**Thanks for help :)**

EDIT NEW Java Script:

```
function checkUsername(idUsername)
// של שדה של שם משתמש id הפעולה מקבלת
// הפעולה מחזירה אמת אם שם המשתמש עומד בתנאי התקינות, ושקר אחרת
{
    var username = document.getElementById(idUsername);
    var flag = true;
    alert(username.length);

    if (username.length < 3)
    {
        // err_UserName הוא השם של הטי די של השגיאה שם שם המתשמש
        document.getElementById("err_UserName").innerHTML = "<p>Username must be at least 3 characters long</p>";
        flag = false;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < username.length; i++) {
        if (!((username.charCodeAt(i) >= 48 && username.charCodeAt(i) <= 57) || (username.charCodeAt(i) >= 65 && username.charCodeAt(i) <= 90) || (username.charCodeAt(i) >= 97 && username.charCodeAt(i) <= 122)))
        {
            document.getElementById("err_UserName").innerHTML = "<p>The username must contain only numbers and alphabetical letters</p>";
            flag = false;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Html (relevant code):

```
<input type="submit" id="submit_Submit" name="submit_Submit" value="Submit" onclick="return checkUsername('text_UserName')">
```

EDIT New Html code, as requested:

```
<th>User Name: (Maximum 10 digits)</th>
<td><input type="text" id=" UserName" name="text_UserName"></td>
<td><p id="err_UserName"></p></td>
```

Comment: what is not working? this is not enough code. Post the HTML element with the username too

Comment: Seems mostly fine. Where is it failing?

Comment: Seems to work https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/0askc537/

Comment: You have an extra space in the ID, `UserName` and you're trying to get element by its _name_ attribute, and not by its ID

Comment: This is the first error I get (in the getElementById().value): Unhandled exception at line 5, column 5 in http://localhost:58608/js1.js
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference occurred

Comment: @DanS Change `id=" UserName"` to `id="UserName"` (Remove the space) and then get the element using `document.getElementById('UserName')`

Comment: @AlonEitan Please see the new Java Script code. Still doesn't work. the error:  Unhandled exception at line 7, column 5 in http://localhost:58608/js1.js
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference occurred

Comment: @DanS You're now getting the DOM element itself, what I meant was is to get the value of that element `document.getElementById('UserName').value` and with your updated code, you're passing the id to the function, but you're passing `text_UserName` instead of the ID attribute of that element (Which is `UserName` (With space from the left at the moment, that you need to remove)

Comment: @AlonEitan Why can't I use the parameter idUsername of the function?

Comment: @DanS Check this out https://jsfiddle.net/4zg3crwt/1/

Comment: @AlonEitan Thank you so much! The only problem that still is left is that if 2 things are illegal (for example, for '#' I want it to write _Username must be at least 3 characters long_ and ALSO _The username must contain only numbers and alphabetical letters_). Can you please help? Thank you so much!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4zg3crwt/2/

Comment: Sorry - https://jsfiddle.net/4zg3crwt/6/

Comment: @AlonEitan Excellent! Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

This should be working if the html element is an `<input id="text_UserName" type="text" />`

```
var username = document.getElementById('text_UserName').value;
```

See: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp

Comment: So what should I do instead? Thanks